# Search for buttons in jpanel and get the button's text?

Tags: java, swing

Hi I have a problem about getting the text from the buttons in a JPanel. My program will have a JPanel and there are 4 buttons inside it. Each button will have a random integer shown as a text. I want my program to be able to get the key that is pressed from the keyboard, and check if that key is matched with any of the buttons' text (Something like the calculator).
If the key is matched with any buttons in the JPanel, it will print out that key and make that button disabled.

My code is something like:

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    Component[] comp = numpanel.getComponents();
    for (int i = 0;i<comp.length;i++) {
        if (comp[i] instanceof JButton) {

             //check if it matches with any button's text

        }
    }
}
```

and I get an error when I try to write comp[i].getText() in order to check the key and the button's text. In my understanding, it says that comp[i] is a Component, which doesn't have the method getText(), am I understand it correctly ?

How can i fix it or are they any alternative ways to do this?

Comment: When you generate the random text for the JButtons, save the text in a model class.  That way, you don't have to retrieve the text from the JButton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it says that comp[i] is a Component, which doesn't have the method getText(), am I understand it correctly ?

Yes.

> How can i fix it or are they any alternative ways to do this?

If you know that `comp[i]` is a JButton, such as within the if statement you have where you checked that it is with `instanceof`, then you can cast it as a JButton, and use the getText() method.

```
.... = ((JButton)comp[i]).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it works now. But I have a few more question to ask, about the method getClass(). Can I check that the component in JPanel is a button or not by using getClass(). Something like if comp[i].getClass is JButton ?

Comment: @KongponCharanwattanakit You could compare `myButton.getClass()` with `JButton.class`, but you may not want to, because you would be restricting your comparison to only actual JButtons and not any custom subclasses of JButton, which should be an okay thing to compare to because any class you make that extends JButton should still be considered in all cases a JButton (if coded following the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).